# How to use array_slice in this type $_POST['MetaData']['video_title'][$index]

Tags: php, arrays, yii, slice

How to use array_slice in this type of array
$_POST['MetaData']['video_title'][$index]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Gets the first three elements
$array2 = array_slice($_POST['MetaData']['video_title'], 0, 3);
```

Like with any other array

Comment: Thank you so much 
its working